# detect if element still exists

Tags: javascript, tags, element

Is there a way to determine if a an element that is saved into a variable still exists on the document? I tried the following and it will not put out the console.log() when the second INPUT tag was deleted.

```
<input type="text">
<input type="email">
<input type="tel">

<script>

var ref= [document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0], document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[1], document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[2]];

document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[1].outerHTML = '';

if (!document.contains(ref[1])) {
    console.log('deleted')
}

</script>
```

Comment: You can try `elementVariable.parentNode`.  If the element does not exist in the DOM, it will not have a parent node, unless it remains a part of a document fragment.

Comment: I would use `querySelectorAll` if you insist on an Array, so you won't have a live collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because you deleted the element at index `1`, which shifts the element at index `2` down to that index.

In general, don't do all that DOM selection. Select once to a variable, and reuse that collection. That's definitely not the way to convert a collection to an array.

However, even with a cached list, it's still is a live list, so the same reindexing will still happen.

Therefore, store that element to its own variable, then test it.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');

var barElem = inputs[1];

barElem.remove();

if (!document.contains(barElem)) {
    console.log('deleted')
}
```

```html
<input value="foo"><input value="bar"><input value="baz">
```

Also, using `.outerHTML = ''` is a pretty hackish way to remove an element, so I updated it to use `barElem.remove()`.

Comment: Which one is better? contains() or element.parentNode? Or does it not matter?

Comment: @janeperritson: An element that has been removed from the DOM may still have a `.parentNode` if it was removed via its ancestor being removed. The `.contains()` method is meant for this purpose, so I'd use that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I would code:

```js
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q; // for use on there loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
// magic under here
const inputs = Q('.main>input');
inputs[1].remove();
if(!bod.contains(inputs[1])){
  console.log('removed');
}
}); // end load
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; color:#000; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
.main{
  background:#333; overflow-y:auto; padding:10px;
}
input{
  margin-left:7px;
}
input:first-child{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <input type='text' /><input type='email' /><input type='tel' />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I took the spaces out between the inputs because one or more white spaces in HTML equals one white space of the current font-size of the Element containing the white space. Also, it's a best practice to use external CSS and JavaScript, so it's cached.

Comment: This is a good micro-library approach. Sure beats using bloated old-school dependencies.